# Power source-based resolutions using AppleScript and Controlplane?

Tags: applescript, automation, resolution

I've been searching for a good applescript to automatically change my resolution based on my power source and/or shortcuts.
For context I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4 and I'm new to scripting, I want to setup a script to change my resolution from 1710 x 1112 when I'm on battery, to 2560 x 1664 when I'm connected to power.
I have found a way to activate the script when changing power sources courtesy of [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/auto-change-mac-screen-resolution-when-switching-power-sources/). Now I just need the script. [image]
Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: See the answers in the two questions linked on top. It actually might be easier to use one of the specific utilities than to script System Settings.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. As you wrote, you already know how to trigger a command if the power source changes, so the missing piece is code to actually change resolutions. This is covered in the answers to the two existing questions linked above.

Comment: @nohillside the code is limited to the default resolution options. Default, Larger text, more Space etc. But I want to set the resolution to 2560 x 1664 specifically which is buried under the toggle (Show all resolutions)

Comment: Please look at the existing answers, some of them should allow to select any resolution.